# How to get my cron job to output its exit code to a file

Tags: unix, path, cron

The cron job I am trying to implement is:

```
0 1 * * * /Users/kfchicken2go/Cron_Job
```

Cron_Job is:
    `SHELL=/bin/zsh`
    `PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`
    `brew update && brew upgrade; echo $? > Cron_OutPut`

Cron_OutPut being the file I want the exit code captured in

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to output from the cronjob call itself like this:

0 1 * * * /Users/kfchicken2go/Cron_Job > Cron_OutPut 2>&1